# NET FILE - file handle values in id column are extremely high

Tags: windows-server-2008, files

Windows Server 2008 Standard SP1

If I issue NET FILE at the prompt, the file handle values in the id column are extremely high, for example '2416032768' would be typical. Is this something to worry about? Not seeing anything in the Windows logs etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handle is a unique number assigned by the OS. The range would be at least 31 bits, allowing handles to have values of over 2 billion. The actual number assigned would depend on the internal algorithm used to map the handle to a file control block in the kernel.

Often, even if only a limited number of concurrent handles are available, a large range can be  used to ensure that there is no unintended collision caused by use of stale handles by broken applications.

The numbers are distributed widely in the available space. You would need to review the specification or code to see how they are allocated.